# Postgres odd behavior with indices

Tags: postgresql, index

I've got a `datavalue` table with ~200M rows or so, with indices on both `site_id` and `paramter_id`. I need to execute queries like "return all sites with data" and "return all parameters with data". The `site` table has only 200 rows or so, and the `parameter` table has only 100 or so rows.

The `site` query is fast and uses the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select *
from site
where exists (
      select 1 from datavalue
      where datavalue.site_id = site.id limit 1
);

Seq Scan on site  (cost=0.00..64.47 rows=64 width=113) (actual time=0.046..1.106 rows=89 loops=1)
  Filter: (SubPlan 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 39
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.44..0.47 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=128)
          ->  Index Only Scan using ix_datavalue_site_id on datavalue  (cost=0.44..8142.71 rows=248930 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=128)
                Index Cond: (site_id = site.id)
                Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.361 ms
Execution time: 1.149 ms
```

The same query for parameters is rather slow and does NOT use the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select *
from parameter
where exists (
      select 1 from datavalue
      where datavalue.parameter_id = parameter.id limit 1
);

Seq Scan on parameter  (cost=0.00..20.50 rows=15 width=2648) (actual time=2895.972..21331.701 rows=15 loops=1)
  Filter: (SubPlan 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 6
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.34 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1015.790..1015.790 rows=1 loops=21)
          ->  Seq Scan on datavalue  (cost=0.00..502127.10 rows=1476987 width=0) (actual time=1015.786..1015.786 rows=1 loops=21)
                Filter: (parameter_id = parameter.id)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 7739355
Planning time: 0.123 ms
Execution time: 21331.736 ms
```

What the deuce is going on here? Alternatively, whats a good way to do this?

Some of the table description:

```
id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('datavalue_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
value DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
site_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
parameter_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
deployment_id INTEGER,
instrument_id INTEGER,
invalid BOOLEAN,
Indexes:
    "datavalue_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "datavalue_datetime_utc_site_id_parameter_id_instrument_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (datetime_utc, site_id, parameter_id, instrument_id)
    "ix_datavalue_instrument_id" btree (instrument_id)
    "ix_datavalue_parameter_id" btree (parameter_id)
    "ix_datavalue_site_id" btree (site_id)
    "tmp_idx" btree (site_id, datetime_utc)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "datavalue_instrument_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (instrument_id) REFERENCES instrument(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "datavalue_parameter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parameter_id) REFERENCES parameter(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "datavalue_site_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES coastal.site(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "datavalue_statistic_type_id_fkey"
```

Edit: Here's the count distribution

```
select count(parameter_id), parameter_id from datavalue group by parameter_id

88169   14
2889171 8
15805   17
8570    12
4257262 21
3947049 15
1225902 2
4091090 3
103877  10
633764  11
994442  18
49232   20
14935   4
563638  13
2955919 7
```

Comment: Why do you have the `limit` in the sub-query? It's useless and might fool the optimizer into a bad plan

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35658238/330315

Comment: That does appear to be the offender, removed the limit and the index was used. Thanks!

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it, so that the question is marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `limit 1` in  the sub query fixed the problem. [More discussion on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35658238/330315)